# Is there a way to block my site from appearing for certain keywords?

Tags: google, keywords, ranking, google-ranking

I run a single website which has several different domains.  The site on each domain looks largely the same, but contains the name of the client in the title and H1 tags.  The sites are all accessible from Google.

When a user goes to one of the URLs and does a store/shop search, they are only shown stores which belong to that client.

According to webmaster tools, each site has the client's name as the highest ranking keyword, followed by all the other good keywords.  Other clients names are not included in the list.  I'm completely happy with what Google has indexed and the keywords it has found.

But the problem is that when searching using keywords that include one clients name, one of the other sites will beat it in the rankings.  I think this is because this other site has a list of stores about 5 times larger than the others - so it is a larger site with similar keywords, so it always wins.

So what I'm wondering is - is there a way to tell Google that if a certain keyword is searched for to not show this site?

This way, I would be able to put all "other" client names in some kind of "exclude list" for each client's site.

I've a feeling this can't be done, having done much Googling on the subject, but I'm hopeful there may be a solution.

Comment: No, there is not

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this (thanks @John Conde). The keywords chosen for the site are chosen by Google based on its assessment when indexing the page and site in question. Any time those keywords are searched for if your site is considered to be a match then your site will be brought up in the results page. No way to change this other than to remove the keywords in question from appearing anywhere in your site and waiting for the site to be recrawled and reindexed and even then no certainty that the keywords won't still be considered valid for your site.